# Div horizontal aligning, one fixed, one adaptive

Tags: css, html, alignment

I would like to create a vertical splitted site structure using two divs:

```
<div id="d1" style="width:100px;float:left"></div>
<div id="d2" style="width:auto;float:left"></div>
```

My intention is to have d2 next to d1 in a horizontal align structure (same line).
What i get is not this.
In fact using that code, d2 does not take the remaining space, but collapses to the min width.

if I use

```
<div id="d1" style="width:100px;float:left"></div>
<div id="d2" style="width:100%;float:left"></div>
```

WRONG because d2 goes down and takes all the space (but both divs are in different lines).

HOW TO REACH MY OBJECTIVE? Is there a design pattern for this problem????

Thanks.

---

OK THIS SHOULD BE THE RIGHT QUESTION...

Hello everyone. I would like to create a vertical splitted site structure using two divs:

```
<div id="d1" style="width:100px;float:left"></div>
<div id="d2" style="width:auto;float:left"></div>
```

My intention is to have d2 next to d1 in a horizontal align structure (same line). What i get is not this. In fact using that code, d2 does not take the remaining space, but collapses to the min width.

if I use

```
<div id="d1" style="width:100px;float:left"></div>
<div id="d2" style="width:100%;float:left"></div>
```

WRONG because d2 goes down and takes all the space (but both divs are in different lines).

HOW TO REACH MY OBJECTIVE? Is there a design pattern for this problem????

Thanks.

Comment: sorry there were problems in posting the code:
this is the first code:
<div id="d1" style="width:100px;float:left"></div>
<div id="d2" style="width:auto;float:left"></div>
and this the second
<div id="d1" style="width:100px;float:left"></div>
<div id="d2" style="width:100%;float:left"></div>

Comment: I think HTML/CSS questions have to be the biggest offenders of poor wording. Please design some diagrams and upload the pictures or take a screenshot of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

U might want to use a table like this:

```
<table width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100px"> </td>
<td width="100%"> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it is the result I would like to obtain, but using table for creating layouts is a deprecated approach, i would like to find a way to do the same thing using CSS...

Answer (score 0):

CSS APPROACH:

```
<div style="width:100%; position:relative">
<div style="width:100px;float:left"> </div>
<div style="width:100%;position:absolute;padding-left:100px;left:0;top:0"> </div>
</div>
```